# Como fazer um INNER JOIN em uma unica tabela com 3 chaves?

Tags: mysql, sql, query, inner-join

Tenho um tabela que possui a seguinte estrutura:

```
origem|papel|campo018|campo040|mercado|Master_key|
```

A coluna `Master_key` pode ter dois valores: `'NY'` OU `'MS'`, gostaria de comparar as linhas em que Master_key é igual a `'NY'` com as que são `'MS'`, as colunas origem, papel e mercado são chaves.

Tentei desta forma, porém não funcionou:

```
SELECT ny.*, ms.* FROM z_quotes ny
INNER JOIN z_quotes ms ON ny.origem = ms.origem
INNER JOIN z_quotes ms ON ny.papel = ms.papel
INNER JOIN z_quotes ms ON ny.mercado = ms.mercado
WHERE (ny.Master_key = 'NY') AND (ms.Master_key = 'MS');
```

Por exemplo, se eu tenho a tabela abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero que retorne desta forma:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer mas com certeza não é com `INNER JOIN`, ele serve para fazer consultas unindo tabelas diferentes. Poderia dar um exemplo de saída esperada?

Comment: Adicionei um exemplo na pergunta

Comment: A relação entre as duas linhas é se todas as colunas forem iguais porém `Master_key` diferente?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam  `Master_key` só pode ter dois resultados, por isso tem um Where no final da query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, basta um `JOIN`:

```
SELECT ny.*, ms.* FROM z_quotes ny
INNER JOIN z_quotes ms ON ny.origem = ms.origem
  AND ny.papel = ms.papel
  AND ny.mercado = ms.mercado
WHERE (ny.Master_key = 'NY') AND (ms.Master_key = 'MS');
```